# Redirect all folders to subdomains htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect every folder from `domain.com` to it's subdomain.

**Examples:**

```
domain.com/a -> a.domain.com
domain.com/b -> b.domain.com
domain.com/about -> about.domain.com
```

So basically, every folder redirected to it's subdomain. For the first example, folder a contains *index.html*. When I browser to domain.com/a it should redirect the url to a.domain.com but use the index.html file from the a folder.

My current htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/%1/


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ %1/index.html [L]
```

**What works**
For now, if I navigate to test.domain.com, it's working, it's taking the index.html file from the test folder. If I go to domain.com/test it's still working, but I want to disable this. I want to redirect domain.com/test to test.domain.com as well, but still use the index.html files from the test folder.

Another thing that is in the htacces file is to redirect www to non-www.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Forgot to mention that I've tried to add this line:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test/(.*)$ http://test.domain.com/$1
```

It's doing the redirection from domain.com/test to test.domain.com/index.html, but it's not loading the page right, I get an error (Page isn't redirecting properly).

Answer (score 1):

keep like
RedirectMatch 301 ^{RELATIVE PATH}$ {ABSOLUTE_PATH}

Comment: I just edited the question. I tried that, but and it's redirecting the url, but I get an error in browser.